# JDBC Object List IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, jdbc

What i am trying to do is i want to be able to pull fields from multiple JDBC Objects so i can use it to name a folder specifically for a client, I have added instances of each required object to retrieve the data to name the client folder and the file to go in that folder as well as the data that needs to go in that file

Here is the code that i am having issues with

```
java.util.List<TransactionItemBean> transactionItems = transactionItemDAO.findAllForTransaction(transactionNo);
java.util.List<TransactionBean> transactions = transactionDAO.findAll();
java.util.List<BuyerBean> buyers = buyerDAO.findAll();
java.util.List<VehicleBean> vehicles = vehicleDAO.findAll();
    for (int i = 0; i <transactionItems.size(); i++) {
        String client = buyers.get(transactions.get(transactionNo-1).getBuyerId()).getSurname_organization();
        String vehiclePlate = vehicles.get(transactionItems.get(i).getVehicleId()).getPlate_no();
        String vehicleMake = vehicles.get(transactionItems.get(i).getVehicleId()).getMake();
        String vehicleModel = vehicles.get(transactionItems.get(i).getVehicleId()).getModel();
```

From what i can see is it seems as though the issue is being caused by the nested JDBC Objects but i am not sure about how to resolve this issue

Comment: What line throws the Exception? How do you know that transactionNo-1 is in transactions?

Comment: What is `transactionNo`? Why do you use `transactionNo-1` instead of `i`? Can you show the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry transactionNo is passed into the function, I ran a debug without the -1 and it was retrieving the next element but not the one I needed

Comment: The exception trace just points to String client = buyers.get(transactions.get(transactionNo-1).getBuyerId()).getSurname_organization();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are getting an item from a list it is by the list index. That is:

```
  buyers.get(i)
```

will return the ith item from the buyers list. You are passing the buyer id as the index. This id may not correspond to the index of the buyer object in the list. Suppose you have 100 buyers and one of them have an id of 230. Then you will actually be attempting to get the 230th item from a list with only 100 items in it. Hence the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

And that seems to be the probel with the way you are accessing all the lists. It appears that you need to implement some way to search your list.

Comment: The idea is nothing will be removed from the database therefore all I am really missing is a -1 on the id's as the id's start at 1 where the indexes start at 0

Answer (score 0):

Vincent Ramdhanie is right.

Instead of using a List, you could use a Map to store your Vehicles.

Maps store key-value pairs.
transactionItems.get(i).getVehicleId() would be your map key,
and VehilceBean would be your value.